# MVC make field be required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to make a field required.
From the model, it already created for a field called DataVal which is part of entity (table) **data_Input** which was automatically created when I added it to the EntityFramework.

Note that in Entityframework it already creted the following:

```
    public global::System.String DataVal
    {
        get
        {
            return _DataVal;
        }
        set
        {

        }
```

What I need to do is to make the DataVal field be required.

I have the following:

```
        public partial class data_Input
        {
          [Required]
          public string DataVal{ get; set; }
        }
```

I get an error though that says there is already a definity for DataVal elsewhere.

My question is that due to entity framework already creating things, how do I go about making a certain field be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll need a `MetaDataType` attribute on your class, with a separate validation class.

See [this link](http://dotnetslackers.com/SQL/re-309931_Adding_Attributes_to_Generated_Classes.aspx) for details.

From that article:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Dinner_Validation))] 
public partial class Dinner 
{} 

public class Dinner_Validation 
{ 
    [Required] 
    public string Title { get; set; } 
}
```